# QT5, How do i use QML from a DLL?

Tags: dll, qml, qt5

I want to build a DLL from some QML so that it can be deployed

modules.pro:

```
TARGET = modules
INCLUDEPATH += .
QT += core qml quick 
TEMPLATE = lib
RESOURCES += MyStuff.qrc
```

MyStuff.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Stuff/qmldir</file>
        <file>Stuff/random.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Under windows, I do, qmake, then nmake (VS2013) and it builds a DLL called modules.dll

I try to use this as follows:

create a directory "imports" inside my project, and place

```
   ./imports/Stuff/modules.dll
```

then `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("imports");
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

and `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Stuff 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: demo
    ...
}
```

error, module "Stuff" is not installed.

I've no idea what im doing, just muddling in the dark.

can anyone help me. thanks.

Comment: Does you plugin extends `QQmlExtensionPlugin`? Does `./imports/Stuff` folder contains `qmldir` file? Read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) page to understand QML plugin creating.

Comment: Not sure this is a plugin as such. I don't extent QQmlExtensionPlugin, what happens is qmake/make converts the .qrc files to .cpp and compiles them. There's no .cpp code of mine here.

Now I'm not sure you can do this; bundling QML into a module that is. If so, how to deploy without just copying over the QML source tree?

not sure what would go into the qmldir. tried

    "module Stuff
    plugin Stuff"

but no go.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, as I understand you want to put your `*.qml` files into external library.
I can offer 2 ways to do that:

1. Create QML plugin following [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html). The plugin can contain resourse `*.qrc` file where you can put `*.qml` files
2. Create external binary resourse. Just create empy *.qrc file and put inside all resources you want including `*.qml` files. Then compile it:

```sh
$QTPATH/bin/rcc -binary/path/to/your.qrc /path/to/binary.rcc
```

and so now you can include compiled resource file in your application's main.cpp:

```
QResource::registerResource("/path/to/binary.rcc");
```

After that you can use all qml items defined in external resource file. For example, if you have MyItem.qml file in `binary.rcc` you can use it as `MyItem {}` in local qml files.

Comment: thanks. I tried the plugin method, but when i try to load the DLL, i get "plugin cannot be loaded for module "Stuff": Plugin verification data mismatch...". plugin code, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d44186e58fb8f733e38 project code, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b3fa453d69088eec383